# Olivetti d-color mf-559 printer

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, printers, network-printers

I have a Olivetti d-color mf-559 printer. I am facing an error code C2152: Transfer belt fault at initial position return.

I perform the below steps:

1. Cleaning of transfer belt
2. Reinstallation of Transfer belt
3. Bought a new transfer belt and installed on it
4. Perform error clean
   After installing new transfer belt, it is still not working. Please suggest me some solution ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su], but please check their documentation to make sure this is on-topic there before you post.

Answer (score -1):

I got an answer for my above question. The issue is with the lever attached to transfer belt. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).